# How to split a date range in 5 days chunks for many years?

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to automate an API Request to Google Analytics using googleAnalyticsR.

The problem is that with so many data, the Query has to be splitted into smaller chunks to retrieve the data correctly.

> The last chunk should take the last day from the last API call, sum 1
>   day. And for the end_date it should be the day before today.

I'would like a way to split a large range, for example: `2017-01-01` to `2020-02-21` in chunks of 5 days, and make an API call using each chunk, so API don't collapse.

Expected  `data frame` output:

```
starts       ends
1  2017-01-01 2017-01-05
2  2017-01-06 2017-01-10
3  2017-01-11 2017-01-15
...
n  2020-02-17 today-minus-1-day
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've found this similar code, on Mark's github repository.

It returns a df with start and end dates, on a montlhy base.

```
add_months <-  function(date, n){
  seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
}

make_date_ranges <- function(start, end){

  starts <- seq(from = start,
                to =  Sys.Date()-1 ,
                by = "1 month")

  ends <- c((seq(from = add_months(start, 1),
                 to = end,
                 by = "1 month" ))-1,
            (Sys.Date()-1))

  data.frame(starts,ends)

}

## useage
make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), Sys.Date())
```

At the end make_date_ranges outputs a df with the start and end dates, in monthly bases, I need it make it output 5 days range chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the question edit, I believe the following function does what the question asks for.

```
make_ranges_day <- function(from, to = Sys.Date(), n = 5){
  from <- as.Date(from)
  to <- if(to == Sys.Date()) Sys.Date() - 1 else as.Date(to)
  by = paste(n, "days")
  starts <- seq(from, to - n + 1, by = by)
  ends <- seq(from + n - 1, to, by = by)
  last <- length(starts)
  remaining <- to - ends[last] + 1
  if(remaining != 0){
    starts <- c(starts, ends[last] + 1)
    ends <- c(ends, to)
  }
  data.frame(starts, ends)
}

chunks <- make_ranges_day("2017-01-01")

head(chunks)
#      starts       ends
#1 2017-01-01 2017-01-05
#2 2017-01-06 2017-01-10
#3 2017-01-11 2017-01-15
#4 2017-01-16 2017-01-20
#5 2017-01-21 2017-01-25
#6 2017-01-26 2017-01-30

tail(chunks)
#        starts       ends
#225 2020-01-26 2020-01-30
#226 2020-01-31 2020-02-04
#227 2020-02-05 2020-02-09
#228 2020-02-10 2020-02-14
#229 2020-02-15 2020-02-19
#230 2020-02-20 2020-02-21
```

Comment: thank you, I'm looking into this code. right now it outputs a all the dates, when I only need a start and end date, of 5 days size. Again thank you, and if you have some time, please see at my updated question.

Comment: `make_ranges_day("2019-12-01", to = "2019-12-31", n = 5)` gives: `Error in to - n : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @OmarGonzales I forgot to coerce to class `"Date"` in the first `if` statement. Done, see now.

Comment: Thank you, I just catched another bug: for `n = 1` the last range returns the previous date: `make_ranges_day("2019-12-01", to = "2019-12-31", n = 1)` returns: 
`30 2019-12-30 2019-12-30`, 
`31 2019-12-31 2019-12-31`,
`32 2020-01-01 2019-12-31` look at this line. in the other cases it works great, ty.